# spring boot app run time error, trying to load file which doesn't exist in the project ( CompositeHealthIndicatorConfiguration)

Tags: java, spring, classpath, cloud-foundry

We have standard spring boot app and while booting, it's showing below error in console. However, looking at spring dependency tree, there is no lib which has this file which make sense. The actual lib which has this file has a different folder path that it is showing. Cleaned the project, and tried rebuilding without luck. No lib conflicts in maven dependency tree as well. Not sure at run time why spring is looking at the folder location for that file. The version which actually has this actuator file is nowhere imported in my project. Inspected the final artifact jar also to make sure correct spring-actuator version is used and it is but at runtime, it is somehow trying to look up that folder. Advise if you have seen this kind of issue before. Thanks.

ERROR:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.jpmorgan.pb.credit.lc.sbl.workflow.LcSblWorkflowServiceApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/CompositeHealthIndicatorConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

In above message, the file path should be ( based on the spring libs in project ):

**/autoconfigure/health/CompositeHealthIndicatorConfiguration.class

Lib version in project :

spring-boot-autoconfigure : 2.2.13-RELEASE

spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure: 2.2.13-RELEASE

spring-boot-actuator: 2.2.13-RELEASE

Above versions are shown in maven dependency tree, no other version is shown.

Thanks in advance!

Update :
Please note, i am using intellij and tried reviewing the jar conflicts for actuator but did not find any. Also inspected generated jar which has same jar libs as shown in intellij.
The file in error could have been in old version of spring which in our firm, is not even available in internal maven repo to use. I tried directly accessing that class in error but could not locate internally ( could not get the jar dependency for that class ).

### *adding some details from POM.*

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>ntest</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.15-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>lc-sbl-workflow</artifactId>
    <name>lc-sbl-workflow</name>
    <description>Core SBL Workflow Services</description>
    <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <xsd.build.dir>${basedir}/src/main/resources</xsd.build.dir>
        <generated.source.location>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/src</generated.source.location>
        <!-- below required for int-service ends -->
        <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

     
        <!-- retry mechanism -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>-->
       
        <!-- Spring-boot-data JPA dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- spring-boot-data JPA, default tomcat pool, exclude it -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- IBM MQ Starter dependencies -->
      
        <!-- This generates the spring-configuration-metadata.json file -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- lombok dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- trail-kafka-client -->
        <dependency>
             <artifactId>trail-kafka-client</artifactId>
            <version>${trail.kafka.client}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Optional dependencies for H2 in-memory database -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cucumber -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--lc-shared dependency for Splunk-->
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CAM generation dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Raven upgrade -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j-ImportXHTML -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-ImportXHTML</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring OXM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jtidy/jtidy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jtidy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
            <version>r938</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
               
        <!-- Optional dependencies Active MQ embedded broker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activemq-openwire-legacy</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dp Core Cryptography library -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
              <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.esapi/esapi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>-->

       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
       
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateDirectory>${generated.source.location}</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${xsd.build.dir}</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>LDPRequestSchema.xsd</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                        <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                        <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <enableSshAgent>true</enableSshAgent>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                    <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <!-- profiles for AIM-vagade starts -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>jenkins</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources-filtered</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                            <layout>ZIP</layout>
                            <addResources>true</addResources>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>repackage-id</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>buildinfo-id</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <additionalProperties>
                                        <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
                                        
                                    </additionalProperties>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>blackduck</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.antrun.plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-blackduck-zip</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" tofile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-blackduck.zip" />
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
  
</project>
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example right now your problem is too big for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe it is a conflicting library. Can I have your pom?

Comment: Thanks. added the details as per your request. Also provided additional comments in update section.